# Bash script in parallel with multiple IP addresses

Tags: linux, bash, logging, parallel-processing

I want to create script, which one logging information from different IP's and in the same time it writes logs to different file, it should run like while:true, but when i start script it logs only first ip address in text file,  what i already tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
IP=`cat IP.txt`
for i in $IP
do
/usr/bin/logclient -l all -f /root/$i.log $i 19999
done
```

IP.txt file contains:

x.x.x.x

x.x.x.x

x.x.x.x

x.x.x.x

Comment: check if you have carriage returns on the ip.txt

Comment: yes it have, i said, script working, but with first item, not with others

Comment: then good luck with your carriage returns.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/parallel -j 53 /usr/bin/logclient -l all -f /root/logs/{}.log {} 19999 < /root/ip.txt

Comment: cant figure out more smarter than this

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your script should work as-is, and if `logclient` works like I think, it'll just create a number of different logs for each IP address. Doing a `ls /root/*.log` should reveal all the logs generated.

Parallelizing execution isn't something bash is particularly good at. It has [job control](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_5.html) for backgrounding tasks, but keeping track of those processes and not overloading your CPU/RAM can be tough.

### GNU Parallel

If your system has it installed, I'd greatly suggest using [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). It will kick off one process for each CPU core to make parellizing jobs much easier. `parallel` only exits when all the children exit.

```
parallel /usr/bin/logclient -l all -f /root/{}.log {} 19999 ::::+ IP.txt
# all jobs finished, post-process the log (if wanted)
cat /root/*.log >> /root/all-ips.log
```

Comment: @robotiaga I don't understand, why wouldn't connecting to a different IP address open a different TCP socket? AFAIK, you can't connect to multiple IP's using the same socket.

Answer (score 0):

rather use while, than for. Something like this:

`while read LINE; do /usr/bin/logclient -l all -f /root/$LINE.log $LINE 19999; done < IP.txt`